# OpenLayers: How to draw a line starting from specific point

Tags: openlayers

This is my very first question here on stackoverflow, I just signed up.
I've got this simple function for drawing a line, works as it should work:

```
function xdraw() {
    routeDraw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer_nautical_route, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {title: 'Draw line'});

    editPanel.addControls(routeDraw);
    editPanel.defaultControl = routeDraw;

    map.addControl(routeDraw);
}
```

Then if you're familiar with OpenLayers, you know you have to click on a map to start drawing the line, but what I want is to set default starting point and then draw from there.
So if you start xdraw() function, first point will be set already (let's say it'd be 0,0).
I hope that makes sense. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to click a button that will call the xdraw function, initialize the DrawFeature control and add the first point all at once, or do you want the first point (eg, 0,0) to be added automatically when you first click on the map once the DrawFeature control is activated? There are a couple of ways of doing this, so need to be clear how you want this to work.

Comment: Thanks John, I want first option. So when I click a button, first point will be drawn automatically on the map (end xdraw function and DrawFeature should be called at the same time, like you mentioned), I hope that helps.